# Saudi transit visa for more than 12hrs layover

Tags: transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I am travelling from Mumbai to Vienna and my layover in Saudi is 10hr 45 min and when I return from Vienna my layover in Saudi is 1hr 45min. Should I apply for a Saudi transit visa?

Comment: No, you do not need transist visa.

Comment: I'm not understanding this. Your title says more than 12hr layover, yet the body seems to indicate an outgoing layover of almost 11hr and a return one of almost 2. Neither of those are over 12. You don't add them up, each flight's layover is separate.